# How to display both old and new values of particular column in sql on html using php?

Tags: php, html, sql

Let us assume there is a `form` which has a `text field` and a `submit button`.

Every time I type a `text` and `submit` it should be **stored in the database** and **displayed in a table**.

Additionally, when I again `submit` the form the old text in SQL column value should be overwritten with this new value and both values should be displayed in table rows.

So every time I do this **I want old data and new data to be appended to table rows**.

How to achieve this??

Comment: You need only the last one and the new one? So if you have data A, I submit with data B ==> you want data A + data B. If I submit data C, you only want data B + data C, that's it? And what if user reload page, should he still saw data B + data C or only the last one (data C)?

Comment: No, if u submit data c, i want data a, data b, data c. This goes on for more data.

Comment: And when user reload the page with the form, should he see ALL the data or only the last one? Those data are link to the user or if user A change somehting, user B will see the "old data" too?

Comment: only for a particular user, when the user reloads the page he should see all the data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overwriting the data, why not create a new entry and mark it as active, such that to get the latest data using sql, you `order by primary key desc limit 1`. If you need the old data you ust get the previous entry.

Comment: if suppose there is a user, text in a particular row, for that particular user how can i create a new entry

Comment: In the database table, you need to add a foreign key where you put the id of the user, so for every entry, you save the `user_id` in the database table. when querying, you include `select ... where user_id = 1` assuming user id is 1

Comment: Can u clearly explain with some code, Im not understanding.

Comment: Put up you code so that I can have a clue how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

We have very few information, but here is some idea to achieve it :

1/ Add an `last` field in your table and update it each time you add a new data, then when you display it just get all data and check the `last` field to see which one is the last :

So imagine this table :

```
Table data
===============================
id_data | id_user | data | last
```

When you display it for your user :

```
select * from data where id_user = :id_user order by last desc;
```

This way you will get the last one with `last = 1` (true) first then the other.

And when you submit a new data :

```
// you update all old data as "old"
update data set last = 0 where id_user = :id_user; 
// you create a new data
insert into data (id_user, data, last) values (:id_user, :data, 1);
```

2/ Add a field date so you know wich one are older than other

```
Table data
==================================
id_data | id_user | data | created
```

When you display it for your user :

```
select * from data where id_user = :id_user order by created desc;
```

This way you will get the data order by the created date with the last one first.

And when you submit a new data :

```
// you create a new data with the current date
insert into data (id_user, data, created) values (:id_user, :data, NOW());
```

This solution is better I think so you can have some "historic" of each data.

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: can we insert into HTML table every time after I submit?. Like if i submit 50 i want 50

Comment: If the logic after each reload is the same (the last one first, then the old), you will have nothing to do : just reload your page after each submit after you add the last data and you will have what you want ==> data A --> SUB data B ==> data B / data A --> SUB data C ==> data C / data B / data A, etc.

Answer (score 0):

why not just append it with a pipe character like so... "|entry_data" then just explode it when you need it.

```
var data_array = explode("|",data);
print_r(data_array);
```

Comment: You mean every time i submit a text in the textbox add it into a array?

Comment: not quite. you would just do a sql update to the field.

Comment: UPDATE Table SET Fieldname=CONCAT(Fieldname,'|more_data');

Comment: when you explode it by designating the pipe as the explode character then you can access each entry from an array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all changes **only for some users** then better to save you last value in **main table** and create new **history table** for changes.

```
table_history
id | id_row | field | before | after
```

In this case you can without additional query show last value for some users and all data for others.

In this structure you also can save multiple fields data if you need.
And believe me, saving previous value in your table will make you life is easy in future.

Comment: I want to show changes for all users. Everytime i provide a msg in input it should be stored and displayed on table. each time i submit the form the old data should be remained in the table

Answer (score 0):

In given below code i update field with new one insert data and also append your new data with old I hope this help you

## Form from which you insert and update data

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']){
    $text_field = $_POST['text_field'];
    $query ="SELECT * FROM `table_name`"; //replace with your table name
    $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_row($run);
    $data = $result[1];  
    if(count($result)){
        $last_string = $data.','.$text_field;
        $update= "UPDATE `table_name` SET `text`='".$last_string."'";
        mysqli_query($conn,$update);
    }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO `table_name`(`text`) VALUES ('".$text_field."')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    }
}
 ?>

 <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text_field">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

## view of data which is inserted

```
<?php 
$query ="SELECT * FROM `table_name`";
$run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($run);
if(isset($result) && count($result)){
    echo "<p>$result[1]</p>"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But can you clearly explain what you are doing here

Comment: In above code whenever you submit first time your form then your insert query will run and whenever you submit second,third... time then update query will run and your form data will append with old data, so you can get all old entries as well as new entries of data, i used comma for append old and new entries